# GWT Canvas (2.2.0) Transparent StrokeStyle

Tags: html, gwt, canvas

I am making a drawing application w/ GWT (2.2.0) canvas.

The problem that I'm having is that I can't set the opacity of the color.

HTML5Canvas supports the alpha channel. However through GWT it passes whatever string into a CssColor which drops the alpha.

Meaning in JS this works (I think):

```
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.5)";
```

But in GWT this doesn't (ignores alpha)

```
context.setStrokeStyle("rgba(0,0,0,0.5)");
```

because it transfers to

```
setStrokeStyle(CssColor.make("rgba(0,0,0,0.5)"))
```

And CssColor doesn't support transparency.

Any suggestions on how to go around this issue.

P.S. This is a very needed feature to be able to, say have an eraser and a highlighter.

EDIT: Square erasers can be done using context.clearRect(...), but that's not what I'm going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found for you a nice example [here](http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=2338). I hope it will help you!

Comment: Thanks. I've looked at it before and I don't know how I missed it.

Comment: Turned out my problem was that I was 'stroking' more than once per path and it was coloring the path over and over.